# Angular <router-outlet name="popup"> change URL path structure?

Tags: angular, url, angular-ui-router, popup

I'm using a popup (refering to the docs):
*https://angular.io/guide/router#displaying-multiple-routes-in-named-outlets*

Everything is fine apart from the URL structure:

> /domain/subPath/(popup:myopoup)

How can I change this default structure with parenthesis? 
I would like it to be as follows:

> /domain/subPath/popup

In other words, I want to **remove the brackets** including the **colon** inside the URL.

Inside their documentation the popup also appears in that manner (with brackets)

Here is some code:

**.ts**

```
{
  path: 'mypopup',
  component: MyComponent,
  outlet: 'popup'
},
```

**.html**

```
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { popup: ['mypopup'] } }]">Contact</a>
<router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet>
```

Comment: I do not think that you can do that. You need to have a way to define your multiple URLs and if you remove the parenthesis it'd just be a regular URL without any auxiliary route.

Comment: are you holding more than one router-outlet on your component? if not then you don't  need to named it

Comment: @Ricardo, yes I am,  that's why I have to name this one...

Comment: Like @Maxime says I don't think is possible in a clean way to change the structure of your url and still use the router-outlet capabilities , this is how angular team implemented it. I will look around to see if I find a solution

Comment: @Ricardo, tnx I appreciate that. I'm not sure why the Angular team did it like that offering no alternative... It 's quite unusual

Comment: @eugene_sunic one of the discussions on github is about this subject , If you don't want that kind of routes I suggest you use parameters to handle the components that you display on your component.. is not a good pattern to follow but is a solution

Comment: Could you please provide the page URL in which the discussion is taking place...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can use URL serializer, to change url structure

```
import { UrlTree ,DefaultUrlSerializer, UrlSerializer } from '@angular/router';

export class cleanUrlSerializer extends DefaultUrlSerializer {  
public parse(url: string): UrlTree {
    function cleanUrl(url) {
        return url.replace(/\(|\)/g,'') // for example to delete parenthesis
    }
    return super.parse(cleanUrl(url));
}
}
```

import this class and add it as provider in your module

```
 providers: [
    {
        provide: UrlSerializer,
        useClass: cleanUrlSerializer 
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

That is how Angular handles multiple outlets. I do not think you will be finding a "clean" solution for this. Just dont use name router outlets, then. Have one single router outlet without a name.

```
[routerLink]="['popup']">

{
  path: 'mypopup',
  component: MyComponent
},

<router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet>
```

Unfortunately, it seems like you do have multiple routers in your project, so this is probably not a solution. I will backup the other commenters when they said there currently is not an easy clean way. I also want a different routing solution, so hopefully we can complain enough that they find a new way.