# Angular 4 routing without slashes

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I have a special recomendation so that we can't use slashes in our routes.
Does the angular router provide any option to not use slashes?
We want to use the router to provide queryparams.

**Example**: 
The url should be like this: `http://localhost:4200?item=2&filter=value&site=1`

```
this.router.navigate([], { queryParams: { site: page}});
```

The above code will provide an URL like this: `http://localhost:4200/?site=1`

I tried to set the base href in index.html to an empty string but this does not work.

```
<base href="">
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: hello, you can use angular UrlSerializer to change routes structure check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49618237/4399281

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular provides two strategies we can use to implement client side routing, one is called the

1. HashLocationStrategy
2. PathLocationStrategy

The default in Angular is the PathLocationStrategy.

Either ways, you'll have slash in your routes.

Comment: Thanks, just using HashLocationStrategy and `<base href="">` solved my problem!