# Query Parameters get modified in URL after route in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular4-router

I was following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44865817/7407321 to navigate to a url using queryParams. I am following the 3 way in which we can pass value to url.

```
<a routerLink='/search' queryParams='{query:india,start:0,rows:10,resultDisplay:video,mode:text}'><li [class.active_view]="Display('videos')" (click)="videoClick()">Videos</li></a>
```

But clicking on the link redirects me to this URL

```
http://localhost:4200/search?0=%7B&1=q&2=u&3=e&4=r&5=y&6=%3A&7=i&8=n&9=d&10=i&11=a&12=%2C&13=s&14=t&15=a&16=r&17=t&18=%3A&19=0&20=%2C&21=r&22=o&23=w&24=s&25=%3A&26=1&27=0&28=%2C&29=r&30=e&31=s&32=u&33=l&34=t&35=D&36=i&37=s&38=p&39=l&40=a&41=y&42=%3A&43=v&44=i&45=d&46=e&47=o&48=%2C&49=m&50=o&51=d&52=e&53=%3A&54=t&55=e&56=x&57=t&58=%7D
```

rather than this

```
http://localhost:4200/search?query=india&start=0&rows=10&resultDisplay=video&mode=text
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use property binding to pass parameters, [queryParams]

```
<a routerLink='/search' [queryParams]="{query:'india',start:0,rows:10,resultDisplay:'video',mode:'text'}"><li [class.active_view]="Display('videos')" (click)="videoClick()">Videos</li></a>
```

Comment: Your answer was really helpful but after wrapping the url becomes like this`http://localhost:4200/search?query=undefined&start=0&rows=10&resultDisplay=undefined&mode=undefined`

Comment: The terms are replaced by `undefined`

Comment: try this "{query:'india',start:0,rows:10,resultDisplay:'video',mode:'text'}"

Comment: After wrapping the values for each query in single quotes, and use double quotes for the entire string, I made a query like this `fq:'fq:'url_file_ext_s%3A(avi%2BOR%2Bmov%2BOR%2Bflw%2BOR%2Bmp4)'` .Now in url corresponding string becomes like this `fq=url_file_ext_s%253A(avi%252BOR%252Bmov%252BOR%252Bflw%252BOR%252Bmp4)` which is unexpected

Comment: I do not know how `25` is appended before each number in url.

Comment: please check my answer here, use Url serializer to replace your character  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49618237/4399281

Comment: for your case it's function cleanUrl(url) {
        return url.replace('%25','%') // for example to delete parenthesis
    }

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your queryParams property in square brackets, since it's a property binding.

```
<a routerLink='/search' [queryParams]="{query:'india',start:'0',rows:'10',resultDisplay:'video',mode:'text'}"><li [class.active_view]="Display('videos')" (click)="videoClick()">Videos</li></a>
```

Comment: Your answer was really helpful but after wrapping the url becomes like this `http://localhost:4200/search?query=undefined&start=0&rows=10&resultDisplay=undefined&mode=undefined`

Comment: The terms are replaced by `undefined`

Comment: @AakashSingh try wrapping the values for each query in single quotes, and use double quotes for the entire string. Check out my updated answer.

Comment: After wrapping the values for each query in single quotes, and use double quotes for the entire string, I made a query like this `fq:'fq:'url_file_ext_s%3A(avi%2BOR%2Bmov%2BOR%2Bflw%2BOR%2Bmp4)'` .Now in url corresponding string becomes like this `fq=url_file_ext_s%253A(avi%252BOR%252Bmov%252BOR%252Bflw%252BOR%252Bmp4)` which is unexpected

Comment: I do not know how `25` is appended before each number in url.