# In URL `%` is replaced by `%25` when using `queryParams` while routing in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes, angular4-router

I wanted to navigate to a URL using `queryParams` while Routing in Angular.

```
<a routerLink='/master' [queryParams]="{query:'%US',mode:'text'}"><li (click)="search()">Search</li></a>
```

The URL I wanted to navigate is:

```
http://localhost:4200/master?query=%US&mode=text
```

But when I click on search it navigates me to:

```
http://localhost:4200/master?query=%25US&mode=text
```

I do not know why `25` is appended after the `%` symbol. Can anyone tell me a cleaner way to navigate correctly.

Comment: It is working correctly. `%` is the escape character for URL encoding, so literal `%` characters _must_ be escaped, otherwise your URL is invalid. If this concept is new to you, read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Comment: I tried using `\%` but it is also not working

Comment: No. It *is* working. `%25` is correct. '\' is not an escape character in a URL.

Comment: How can I use % in url or is it not possible?

Comment: Please read what I have said, and follow that link. *You are already using `%` correctly.*

Comment: if you wanna change url structure you can try angular url serializer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49618237/4399281 for your case may be it is:   function cleanUrl(url) {
        return url.replace("%25",'%') 
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In URLs, the percent sign has special meaning and is used to encode special characters. For example, = is encoded as %3D.

Certain special characters are not allowed in url. If you want to use those in url you have to encode them using encodeURIComponent javascript function.
%25 is actually encoded version of % character. Here browser is encoding them itself.

When trying to get queryParams from url , you can decode them using decodeURIComponent.

For more information check : https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/969869/certain-special-characters-are-not-allowed-in-the-url-entered-into-the

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent